# for any $k$,there exist set $B$ (be a permutation of $A$),such $B+A=A$

Tags: number-theory

> Define $A+B=\{a_{i}+b_{i}|1\le i\le n\}$,where $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}\},B=\{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}\}$,
>
> Let $B$be a permutation of $A=\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$
>
> I found there exsit $B$ such $A+B=A$.

For eaxmple:$$A=\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\},B=\{0,1,3,-2,2,-1,-3\}$$
since
$$-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$$
$+$
$$0,1,3,-2,2,-1,-3$$
=$$-3,-1,2,-2,3,1,0$$

> Then, I began to try to find every positive integer $k$ such that the following proposition is true :Let set $A=\{-(2k-1),-2k,\cdots,0,1,\cdots,2k,2k-1\},k\in N^{+}$,>show that: for any $k$,there exist set $B$ (be a permutation of $A$),such $B+A=A$.

However, I've been facing difficulty in the case of $k\ge 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do you for $k=5$, and I trust the general pattern will be clear.

$$\matrix{-9&-8&-7&-6&-5&-4&-3&-2&-1&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\9&7&5&3&1&-1&-3&-5&-7&-9&8&6&4&2&0&-2&-4&-6&-8\\}$$

Comment: why for general pattern will be clear?

Comment: Do you not see a pattern in the permutation? odd numbers, in decreasing order, then even numbers, in decreasing order?

Comment: Are we OK now, inequality?